# how to configure signature for user to be used in email

Tags: email, user

In the email methods there is a `setUseSignature()` method that says it:

"Indicates whether the email includes an email signature if the user has one configured. The default is true, meaning if the user has a signature it is included in the email unless you specify false."

[Link to email method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_Messaging_Email_setUseSignature)

But **how** exactly does one configure such a thing? I cant seem to find anything on it in the documentation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears under My Settings > Email > My Email Settings > Email Signature:

[image: Configure Email Signature]

Comment: thanks! when searching on developerforce it just comes up with a bunch of o-auth stuff or method 'signatures' lol